# How to deal with multiple lookup tables for beginners of SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around multiple lookup tables. I have a central table with all the info but IDs in each column:

```
db_supply (Main supplier information data table)
 -----------------------------------------------
| Supplier_ID | Supply_Type_ID | Itm_ID | Stock |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| 1           | 1              | 33     | 3     |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| 2           | 2              | 28     | 1     |
 -----------------------------------------------

lookup_supplier
 -----------------------------
| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name |
|-----------------------------|
| 1           | Walter        |
|-----------------------------|
| 2           | Jesse         |
 -----------------------------

lookup_supply_type
 -----------------------------------
| Supply_Type_ID | Supply_Type_Name |
|-----------------------------------|
| 1              | Import           |
|-----------------------------------|
| 2              | Delivery         |
 -----------------------------------

lookup_itm
 ------------------------
| Itm_ID | Itm_Name      |
|------------------------|
| 33     | Pickles       |
|------------------------|
| 28     | Burger        |
 ------------------------

A query for 'Burger' will output this table:
 -----------------------------------------------------
| Supplier_Name | Supply_Type_Name | Itm_Name | Stock |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| Jesse         | Delivery         | Burger   | 1     |
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

How would I actually achieve this? So far I have:

`SELECT * FROM db_supply WHERE Itm_ID = (SELECT Itm_ID FROM lookup_itm WHERE Itm_Name = 'Burger')`

Which would give me the second row of the `db_supply` table with IDs not looked up yet. Do I have to nest my selects to look up multiple tables? No idea here.

Comment: what result you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to query an item name and get a return of supplier, supply type, itm name and stock columns for that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.Supplier_Name,
        c.Supply_Type_Name,
        d.Itm_Name,
        a.Stock
FROM    db_supply a
        INNER JOIN lookup_supplier b
            ON a.Supplier_ID = b.Supplier_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_supply_type c
            ON a.Supply_Type_ID = c.Supply_Type_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_itm d
            ON a.Itm_ID = d.Itm_ID
WHERE   d.Itm_Name = 'Burger'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89656/3)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ SUPPLIER_NAME ║ SUPPLY_TYPE_NAME ║ ITM_NAME ║ STOCK ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ Jesse         ║ Delivery         ║ Burger   ║     1 ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: What is `b. c. d. a. in the SELECT clause`? I've seen this before. EDIT: There's an SQLFiddle? Awesome.

Comment: @meiryo they are called `ALIAS`. They are useful if you have longer tables names.

Comment: SQLFiddle is an awesome tool to test sql query online `:)`

Comment: Cool. Just ran a query and performance wise... these are taking 4 seconds each. Is this the best approach or should I look into caching my results somehow? (my data rarely changes).

Comment: you did not define an index right? can you show the structures of the tables?

Comment: can you show the output of theses statements along with your question? `DESC lookup_supplier`,`DESC lookup_supply_type`,`DESC lookup_supply_type`,`DESC db_supply`

Comment: The example above was a simple representation. The `db supply` has an extra column called ID (simply for each row in the table). The look up tables are the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27754/discussion-between-j-w-and-meiryo)

Answer (score 0):

**Try following query:**

```
select b.Supplier_Name,c.Supply_Type_Name,d.itemName  from db_supply a,lookup_supplier b,lookup_supply_type c,lookup_itm d where a.Supplier_ID=b.Supplier_ID and a.Supply_Type_ID=c.Supply_Type_ID and a.Itm_ID=d.Itm_ID and d.Itm_Name='Burger'
```

Comment: I see your solution differs from J W's. Which has better performance?

Comment: I think both queries are same, if you parse this query in mysql, it will automatically create syntax of INNER JOINs[same as JW has given]. You can use any of it.