# How do you JOIN tables to a view using a Vertica DB?

Tags: sql, vertica

Good morning/afternoon! I was hoping someone could help me out with something that probably should be very simple.

Admittedly, I’m not the strongest SQL query designer. That said, I’ve spent a couple hours beating my head against my keyboard trying to get a seemingly simple three way join working.

NOTE: I'm querying a Vertica DB.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT A.CaseOriginalProductNumber, A.CaseCreatedDate, A.CaseNumber, B.BU2_Key as BusinessUnit, C.product_number_desc as ModelNumber
  FROM  pps_sfdc.v_Case A
  INNER JOIN reference_data.DIM_PRODUCT_LINE_HIERARCHY B
    ON  B.PL_Key = A.CaseOriginalProductLine
  INNER JOIN reference_data.DIM_PRODUCT C
    ON  C.product_line_code = A.CaseOriginalProductLine
  WHERE B.BU2_Key = 'XWT'
  LIMIT 20
```

I have a view (v_Case) that I’m trying to join to two other tables so I can lookup a value from each of them. The above query returns identical data on everything EXCEPT the last column (see below). It's like it's iterating through the last column to pull out the unique entries, sort of like a "GROUP BY" clause. What SHOULD be happening is that I get unique rows with specific "BusinessUnit" and "ModelNumber" for that record.

```
DUMEPRINT   5/2/2014 8:56:27 AM 3002845327  JJT Product 1
DUMEPRINT   5/2/2014 8:56:27 AM 3002845327  JJT Product 2
DUMEPRINT   5/2/2014 8:56:27 AM 3002845327  JJT Product 3
DUMEPRINT   5/2/2014 8:56:27 AM 3002845327  JJT Product 4
```

I modeled my solution after this post:

[How to deal with multiple lookup tables for beginners of SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872688/how-to-deal-with-multiple-lookup-tables-for-beginners-of-sql)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: +1 for a well asked question.  This looks data driven though, which makes for troubleshooting answers and not real answers.  C.product_line_code seems like it's got the duplicates...  select product_line_code, count(1) from reference_data.DIM_PRODUCT group by product_line_code having count(1) > 1.   That code there will tell if there are duplicates in the dim_product table by product_line_code...if you get 0 results, the table is clean...more than 1 result will suggest this join is where the duplicates are popping up and show the product_line_code that are causing this isse.

Comment: RE: Twelfth 

That was indeed the problem. The "DIM_PRODUCT" table is not a true lookup table - there where duplicate entries all over the place. Ha ha! I *think* I found the correct table now (there are hundreds of tables) and stuff appears to be working - at least for now. THANK YOU for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: I'll turn the comment into an answer...I learned from a couple years of desktop support that the code and system function just as they should, but dirty data or users attempting to do things the system was never intended for are the root cause of the issue.  If you are sure your joins are good, then check the data for duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data issue.  General rule in trouble shooting these is the column that is distinct (in this case C.product_number_desc as ModelNumber) for each record is generally where the issue is going to be...and why I pointed you towards dim_product.

If you receive duplicates, this query below will help identify if this table is giving you the issues.  Remember key in this statement can be multiple fields...whatever you are joining the table on:

```
Select key,count(1) from table group by key having count(1)>1
```

Other options for the future...don't assume it's your code, duplicates like this almost always point towards dirty data (other option is you are causing cross joins because keys are not correct).  If you comment out the 'c' table and the column referred to in the select clause, you would have received one row...hence your dupes were coming from the 'c' table here.

Good luck with it